# Как запускать скрипт на nodejs по таймеру?

Tags: javascript, node.js, сервер

Есть скрипт написанный на nodejs который должен выполняться каждый час, и после выключиться. Можно сделать это через планировщик задач ОС. Есть ли другие способы решить эту задачу?

Comment: Так а чем Вам планировщик не угодил? Как раз для этого и существует

Comment: этот скрипт должен быть установлен через установщик но я не могу присутсвовать при каждой установке и настраивать планировщик задач. Нужно чтобы после установки этот скрипт сам должен запускаться каждый час

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Вы можете написать этот скрипт с использованием `node-cron`.
   https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron
   Создаете cron.schedule() на каждый час с необходимой логикой
2. Использовать setTimeout/setInterval. Если вам нужно отслеживать конец выполнения скрипта - можно сделать промис https://learn.javascript.ru/promise и после выполнения запускать setTimeout на час.

Чтобы скрипт работал всегда, в том числе автоматически запускался после перезагрузки сервера - используйте `pm2`

Comment: Спасибо, выручили

Comment: Пожалуйста. Рад, что помог)